# HCP Packer connection problem to registry in ADO pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, packer, hcl

I am currently getting the following error in my ADO pipeline when running "packer build". I have set HCP_CLIENT_ID and HCP_CLIENT_SECRET inside my variable group and it is utilizing them to connect to the packer registry but it is saying "access denied" as if my hcp client id and secret are not authorized. I have used the same client credentials on my local and on GitHub actions with no issues during a packer build. Seems to me like there is some api connection blocked on the ADO end or maybe the HCP packer registry end.

Error: HCP: populating iteration failed

Failed to create client connection to artifact registry: status 1: err unable to
fetch organization list: Get
"https://api.cloud.hashicorp.com:443/resource-manager/2019-12-10/organizations":
oauth2: cannot fetch token: 401 Unauthorized
Response: {"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Unauthorized"}

```
trigger:
- 'main'

variables:
- name: packer_file 
  value: ./test.pkr.hcl


stages:
- stage: packer
  jobs:
  - job: packer_deploy
    timeoutInMinutes: 360
    displayName: "Packer-deploy-job"
    steps:
      - checkout: self
      - script: |
          sudo apt update
          sudo apt upgrade
          wget -O- https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg
          echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hashicorp.list
          sudo apt update && sudo apt install packer  
          packer --version
        name: install
        displayName: Install Packer CLI
      - script: |
          packer init ${{ variables.packer_file }}
          packer validate ${{ variables.packer_file }}
        name: init_validate
        displayName: Packer INIT & validate
      - script: |
          packer build --force -color=false -on-error=abort ${{ variables.packer_file }}
        env:
          HCP_API_URL: https://api.hashicorp.cloud
          HCP_CLIENT_ID: $(HCP_CLIENT_ID)
          HCP_CLIENT_SECRET: $(HCP_CLIENT_SECRET)
          HCP_PACKER_BUILD_FINGERPRINT: "run.id.$(Build.BuildId)"
        name: build
        displayName: Packer Build
```

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same error. I remember I removed and again added HCP_CLIENT_ID, HCP_CLIENT_SECRET in the environment variable in my system and restarted. The issue started from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I was adding Azure client id and secret mistakenly to HCP_CLIENT_ID and HCP_CLIENT_SECRET. When updated and restarted the system, it started working.